# Make git diff output more logical

Tags: git, git-diff

When doing git diff, I get

```
 %table.table.table-bordered
   %tr
-    %th Heading1
-    %th Heading2
-  %tr
     %td Content1
     %td Content2
```

But I'd like it to display the first `%tr`, rather than the second, as being deleted:

```
 %table.table.table-bordered
-  %tr
-    %th Heading1
-    %th Heading2
   %tr
     %td Content1
     %td Content2
```

I know that the two would be the same to git, but the latter is easier for me to comprehend. Is it possible to configure git diff to do the latter?

Answer (score 3):

Git has three different diff algorithms, in addition to the default: minimal, patience, and histogram. These can be enabled using the `--minimal`, `--patience`, and `--histogram` options to `git diff`, respectively. You can try out one of the those extra algorithms and see if `git diff` generates a diff more aligned with what you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Unfortunately, none of these three options helped.